# VBA Word: Making a range from cells in a table "Named Argument Not Found"

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2016

I'm trying to set a range of Cell so I can later add content controls to each cell in that range. Right now I have:

`Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Table(1).Cell(Start:=ActiveDocument.Table(1).Cell(2, 4).Range.Start, End:=(ActiveDocument.Table(1).Cell(2, 14).Range.End)`

As far as I am aware that creates the range (Row 2, Column 4 through 14), but when I pass that through it does not return a syntax error but a "Named Argument Not Found" and highlights "Start:=". After I have the range set I should be able to pass the range through:

`Set MyCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControl.Add(wdContentControlDate, MyRange)`

That should create a date picker on each cell in the range as far as I am aware.

Comment: [`Table.Cell` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table.cell).

Comment: @BigBen Unless there is something I am missing, that only defines one cell. In order to define a range of cells you have to use the "range object" and set a range of Cells. That is what I am doing. I am defining the start at (2, 4) and the end at (2, 14). Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range as far as I am aware I am following this page of the documentation correctly.

Comment: You have `ActiveDocument.Table(1).Cell(Start:=`. That's the `Table.Cell` method, which has no `Start` parameter, right? IOW, I believe I'm pointing out your error.

Comment: @BigBen Are you suggesting that I just drop the 'Start:=' and 'End:=' and keep the rest of it? The 'Table.Cell' page only shows how to define a single cell. It does not incorporate a range of cells and only shows how to manipulate a specific single cell.

Comment: I assumed the `Start:=ActiveDocument.Table(1).Cell(2, 4).Range.Start` would've counted as var1 of the arguments for range but now that I say that out loud `Table.Cell` is looking for specifically a row as the first argument. This just leads me back around to "How do I define a range of cells." Do I say `Table(1).Range(2, 4).Range.Start`?

Comment: You cannot create a "a range of Cells" in Word. You may create a `Range` which contains a `Table` that has `Cells` but there is no way to create "a range of Cells". To add a content control to a number of cells you need to loop through the cells adding the control to the range of each cell.